# A specific example of pushforward measure

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of pushforward measure is：
Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f : X \to Y$
be a function between sets. Define
$$f_{\#}(\mathcal{F}):=\left\{B \subset Y: f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}\right\}, \quad\left[f_{\#} \mu\right](B):=\mu\left(f^{-1}(B)\right) \text { for } B \in f_{\#}(\mathcal{F}).$$

We all know $\left(Y, f_{\#}(\mathcal{F}), f_{\#} \mu\right)$ is a measure space.Now let $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be $\left(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mathcal{L}^{1}\right)$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue
measure. There are two specific example:

1.$f(x)=\tan x$  if $\cos x \neq 0$,and $f(x)=0$ if  $\cos x=0$,

2.$f(x)=\arctan x$.

---

How can I determine their $\left(\mathbb{R}, f_{\#}(\mathcal{F}), f_{\#} \mu\right)$?